# Crash during scene transition - Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift2

So I started on this Space Shooter game and I created an "EndGame" screen where the player would click the restart button to go back when they died. The problem is, when they the player tap restart, it just goes to a black blue screen and crashes. The error is

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP Subcode=0x0)

The crash line is in this function

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.fAsteroids) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Asteroids) || (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Asteroids) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.fAsteroids)){

        if let sprite = firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode{
        asteroidsHitEachOther((firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode)!, FuriousAsteroids: (secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode)!)
        }

    }

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Asteroids) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet) || (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Asteroids)){

        if let sprite = firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode{
        bulletHitAsteroids((firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode)!, Bullet: (secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode)!)
        }

    }
    else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.fAsteroids) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet) || (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.fAsteroids)){

        if let sprite = firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode{
        bulletHitfAsteroids((firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode)!, Bullet: (secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode)!)
        }   

    }

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Asteroids) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Fighter) || (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Fighter) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Asteroids)){

        if let sprite = firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode{
        fighterGetHit((firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode)!, Asteroids: (secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode)!)
        }

    }


    else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.fAsteroids) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Fighter) || (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Fighter) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.fAsteroids)){

        if let sprite = firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode{
        fighterGetHitHard((firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode)!, fAsteroids: (secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode)!)
        }

    }

}
```

It would "randomly" choose the lines to crash. The lines that it can crash on are these lines

```
asteroidsHitEachOther((firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode)!, FuriousAsteroids: (secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode)!)

 bulletHitAsteroids((firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode)!, Bullet: (secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode)!)

bulletHitfAsteroids((firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode)!, Bullet: (secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode)!)

fighterGetHitHard((firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode)!, fAsteroids: (secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode)!)
```

Comment: never attempted this, but what happens when you cast a negative number with UInt32?  UInt32(-20).  It may be that your max value is -20 and your min value is 0

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Ok so now the max value isn't -20, but it is still crashing with a blue screen on these lines above ^^^

Comment: if it is failing on the actual function name and not inside the function, then your issue may be that first node is null, but you are unwrapping it.  Just to let you know, the console does print out why something is failing sometimes, look at the console to get more info on your errors

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Well then what should I change my function name too

Comment: Its not the name, i dont know why your nodes are null, like i said look at the console

Comment: @Knight0fDragon The console says `(lldb)` in green letters

Comment: on the bottom of Xcode is a panel called output, that is your console  lldb is just the name of it

Comment: @Knight0fDragon then which one is the console? Is it the one next to the output?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Well here is the picture of the bottom of Xcode and all the things that popped up [https://gyazo.com/7b37f1940c0c2b00022f11e3cea896dd]

Comment: Is that what it looks like on the crash?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon well there is also errors that appear on the code screen as I stated in the post, that's the error that appear in the code hilighted in red